# pushing git tags to gitosis repository

Tags: git

I've set up a git repository using gitosis.

I've cloned the repository, and I work on the cloned copy. I push to the gitosis repository (my "origin" remote) regularly. Whenever I deploy my code, I tag my code.

But I suddenly noticed something strange today: I cloned a fresh copy from my gitosis, but that clone had no tags in it! Running `git tag -l` turned up nothing.

Do git tags not get pushed to remotes when we push? If yes, am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags need to be pushed explicitly:

```
git push --tags origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag codes steps:

(1) `git tag huofarV1.0.1 -am "add a new tag huofarV1.0.1"`
   //  to add a new tag

(2) `git tag`  // show local tag list and you will see the new tag called "huofarV1.0.1"

(3) `git push origin huofarV1.0.1` // the most important step, you should push it  to remote .Then when you git clone code,you can see the tag as well.